# Doorbell transformer diagnosis

Tags: transformer, doorbell

I heard a buzzing noise in the attic in a relatively new to us house, have since learned what a doorbell transformer is, and am trying to figure out what's wrong here.

The facts:

- The buzzing was fairly loud.
- The transformer was hot to the touch. I'd guess 120F - 130F.
- I removed the bell wires and measured 80 ohms between them. This seems low, but maybe I'm not understanding. The 8V output is connected, so that's 100mA.
- I left the bell wires disconnected for half an hour or so, and the transformer did not cool down appreciably.

I've since disconnected the thing from power. Does it seem like there's a short? Maybe two? What else should I have investigated?

Comment: If it's 130 degrees with no load connected just replace it!  Right, you said you disconnected the bell .... to be clear, there is *nothing* connected to the output terminals?    Also since you just moved in, think about what Smart or other doorbell you might get before buying a replacement ... so that you can buy the right one.  Maybe you'll get a battery-powered one and you can just leave this turned off.

Comment: @jay613, thanks for the constructive comment. Yes, I did disconnect the output completely. Does the low resistance of the chime side of the circuit indicate that there's some kind of partial short there, or is 80 Ohms not unreasonable?

Comment: @rolfthegolf -- re-read the first sentence of the comment by jay613. Doorbell transformers are cheap; just replace it.